# First row won´t delete in r

Tags: r, header, row

I'm having an issue with deleting the first cell in R. I have tried many ways but none work.

```
file0 <- read_excel("path")
```

I have tried `file1 <- file0[,-1]` and  `file1 <- file0[-1,-1]` but the result don't catch me the line. Data is from a downloadable excel which I pull to R. This is how it looks:

| Applied filters: |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| Activity | Count | State |
| xx | 2 | Pending |
| xx | 2 | Pending |

Applying `file1 <- file0[-c(1),]` deletes the blank row but not the "applied filters".
I want The "Actity" row to be the header and delete both the blank row and "applied filters" row. Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe try `file0 <- read_excel("path", skip = 2)`?

Comment: There are arguments in `read_excel` that let you skip lines before the data/column headings. Read the manual page at `?read_excel`. You probably cannot salvage your data after the fact. Your numeric data has been converted to character and there may be other problems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

`file0 <- read_excel("path", skip = 1)`

Or  (since I am not completely sure about the structure of your data):

`file0 <- read_excel("path", skip = 2)`